# An easy Real Analysis Problem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I found this Real Analysis problem from the MTRP book published by ISI for class 11. I .

Suppose the function $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, where $b-a\geq 4$. Prove that there is $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(x_0)<1+\big(f(x_0)\big)^2.$$

My ideas of solving : When I first saw the problem I just tracked it from reverse and got idea that this problem involves $\arctan(x)$ . So I considered a function $g(x) = \arctan(f(x))$ . This get's the problem to be transformed to showing that for some real number $c$ we have $g(c) < c$. For this I considered another function $h(x) = g(x) - x$. But at this point Iam struck and have no idea where to go about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the structure $f'(x_0) = 1 + f(x_0)^2$. Which trivially means $g(x) = \tan^{-1}f(x)$ is our required construction on which we will use MVT.

As $x_2- x_1 \geqslant 4 \implies x_2 - x_1 > \pi $.
Then by MVT on $g$ in $[x_1, x_2]$ we have that there exists $x_0 \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that $$ \frac{g(x_2) - g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1 } = g'(x_0)$$ $$ \implies \frac{\tan^{-1} f(x_2) - \tan^{-1} f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = [\tan^{-1}f(x_0)]'= \frac{f'(x_0)}{1 + f(x_0)^2} $$
$$ \implies \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} - (-\frac{\pi}{2}) }{x_2 - x_1} \geqslant \frac{f'(x_0)}{1 + f(x_0)^2} \quad \text{as }\tan^{-1} \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2] $$
$$ \implies 1 > \frac{\pi}{x_2 - x_1} \geqslant \frac{f'(x_0)}{1 + f(x_0)^2} \implies 1 + f(x_0)^2 > f'(x_0)  $$

Comment: Thanks. Iam accepting this answer cause it goes with what Iam thinking.

Comment: Then just upvote it too ;)

Comment: You can also see this one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3793797/745108

Comment: Upvoted , thanks for the reference

Comment: can I know where was the fault in the solution that it was downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

If this is false then the derivative of  $\arctan f(x)$ namely $\frac {f'(x)} {1+f(x)^{2}} $ exceeds or equals $1$.  By MVT $\arctan f(b)-\arctan f(a) \geq (b-a)\geq 4$. But  $\arctan f(b)-\arctan f(a) <\pi$ so we have  a contradiction.

Comment: Shouldn't $\arctan b - \arctan a$ be $\arctan f(b) - \arctan f(a)$?

Comment: @kobe Yes, it was careless typing. Thanks.

Comment: The strict inequality in $\arctan f(b) - \arctan f(a) > b - a$ should be $\arctan f(b) - \arctan f(a) \ge b - a$ since you claimed the derivative of $\arctan f(x)$ is $\ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy for your answer